# Ubuntu installation shuts down at selection menu

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 using USB. After booting from USB, the selection menu comes where it has four options(try Ubuntu,install Ubuntu,OEM installation & check disk) After I select any of the four options, the screen goes dark and then the PC shuts down. I can't proceed from here. 
My PC has windows 10, UEFI firmware, amd APU( a-10 5800k), hard disk partition format is gpt. I have used gpt for uefi mode in rufus while preparing the USB disk.
Please help me. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media ?

Comment: I didnt understand much from that thread. I am pretty basic level user don't have much expertise :(

Answer (score 0):

> "The screen I get after booting is dark, has the four options and shows
>   the grub version at the top. After selecting any one of the options,
>   the screen just turns black and PC shuts down nothing else. I have not
>   tried CD version yet. Will try it soon. And pressing Ctrl+C does not
>   do anything"

Most probably  your usb installation is corrupt, have to say  i tried with several tools and the only tool that have  gibed me a 100% success in installations  of all distros including windows is called " WinSetupFromUSB" which creates installs for all or at least mostly of the OS Linux /windows;
the Only problem is that till i know its a windows app.

My recommendation is that u try the cd way USB can be sophisticated and practical but let me tell ya, CD are just magic if it doesn't work with cd  then u have a hardware problem; would say run a hiren's boot check your HDD, if hiren's don't find HHD that means  its hardware related 100%

Comment: The screen I get after booting is dark, has the four options and shows the grub version at the top. After selecting any one of the options, the screen just turns black and PC shuts down nothing else. I have not tried CD version yet. Will try it soon. And pressing Ctrl+C does not do anything.